# Is there any way to play flash in javafx WebView?

Tags: java, flash, javafx

I need to play video content from web in my javafx app(for win), could i solve this prolem with WebView or is there any other suitable control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) does not support flash playback.

You could try the [Flash Player from the DJ project Native Swing components](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html).  (This is not a recommendation for that project, I have never used it).

Or, you can use [HostServices.showDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29) to open a browser to play the flash content, letting the browser worry about guiding the user through obtaining the appropriate plugin.

Comment: DJ Project is a bad choice:) Try to wrap something around CEF C++ implementation

Comment: Alexey, May I ask why you say it is a bad choice and could you elaborate on the CEF C++ implementation please?

Comment: CEF is the ultimate solution in my opinion. However, it is not production ready and crashes constantly. Other options include MozillaInterfaces and JDIC which both were discontinued a long long time ago. So it appears the only current solution is DJ Native Swing. Christopher Deckers did an absolutely fabulous job and wrote a few thousand lines of code to leverage the SWT browser component to interact with flash. I didn't manage to use this in a SwingNode in javaFx though, so I had to create a Swing application with my javaFx content on a JFXPanel and the display my flash in a JInternalFrame.